# 404 error on letsencrypt renew certificate

Tags: linux, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

Every time I try to renew my letsencrypt certificate it fails with a 404 error using nginx and certbot. I managed to fix it by modifying the configuration file to a basic one, but this prevents the certificate from auto-renewing, so every 3 months I have to repeat the operation. Could you help me to find out where the problem is?

My actual domain conf (acuar.io.conf) -- This code is working to operate the website but not for renewal

```
# Odoo servers
upstream odoo {
 server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}

upstream odoochat {
 server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

# HTTP -> HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.acuar.io acuar.io;

    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://acuar.io$request_uri;
}

# WWW -> NON WWW
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.acuar.io;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/acuar.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/acuar.io/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/acuar.io/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    return 301 https://acuar.io$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name acuar.io;

    proxy_read_timeout 720s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
    proxy_send_timeout 720s;

    # Proxy headers
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    # SSL parameters
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/acuar.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/acuar.io/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/acuar.io/chain.pem;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    # log files
    access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

    # Handle longpoll requests
    location /longpolling {
        proxy_pass http://odoochat;
    }

    # Handle / requests
    location / {
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }

    # Cache static files
    location ~* /web/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
        proxy_buffering on;
        expires 864000;
        proxy_pass http://odoo;
    }

    # Gzip
    gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
    gzip on;
}
```

The code I have to setup to get certificate renewal working:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name acuar.io www.acuar.io;

  include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of tries i managed to make a workaround, I'm sure there may be better options but at least it works:

I commented the line where the code redirects HTTP to HTTPS:

> ```
> # HTTP -> HTTPS server {
>     listen 80;
>     server_name www.acuar.io acuar.io;
>
>     include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
> #   return 301 https://acuar.io$request_uri; 
> }
> ```

The problem, as long as I understood was Cerbot needs to access the server in HTTP but the server was already forcing all trafic to HTTP.

If anyone have a better way to make this i really apreciate the help. In any case I hope this will help someone in the same error like me.

Thanks

Comment: I don't do http->https the same as you - but disabling this in my configuration suddenly caused certbot to work for me!